# Dynmaic Excel Countif

Tags: excel, dynamic, countif

I have a spreadsheet with a list of values and I'm trying to determine the count above a certain threshold.  Using countif, I can hardcode in the threshold of 13.5%...

```
threshold:  13.50%
count above:    5


#   Score   
 1  13.06%  
 2  15.20%  
 3  16.39%  
 4  17.61%  
 5  18.11%  
 6  16.49%  
 7  13.43%  
 8  11.60%  
 9  10.69%  
 10  9.04%  

=countif(B6:B15,">13.5%")
```

produces the desired output of 6.

How do I refer to cell C1 as my threshold instead of hardcoding in >"13.5%" ?

Comment: Concatenate the string with `&`:`">" & C1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the quote marks and add an ampersand.  Something like:

```
=COUNTIF(B6:B15,">" & C1)
```

should work.